# window caption alignment

Tags: winapi

I'm opening OpenGL window according to this [example](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_(win32)/13001/), except I'm doing it in Free Pascal and using W-functions `RegisterClassExW` and `CreateWindowExW`. After spending some time trying to set window caption with `setWindowTextW`, I failed to align this text to left with:

`dc := GetWindowDC(_h_Wnd); // tried with GetDC(_h_Wnd) too
 setTextAlign(dc, TA_LEFT);`

Text stays centered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to get the window captions centered to begin with.  I'm guessing you have some sort of non-standard theme.

Comment: @Adrian. You're right. I noticed, this affects my Windows 8.1 pc, but not the W10 one. I'll investigate more. Thanks for hint.